# Need a pair of compounds that is similar in formula but different in structure

Tags: reference-request

I would like to explain chemical formulas is not representable in terms of the molecular structure of the compound.

Any good suggestions of examples?

Comment: What about carbon? Diamond, graphite, graphene, nanotubes, fullerenes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical example is dimethyl ester $\ce{CH3-O-CH3}$ and etanol $\ce{CH3-CH2-OH}$ pair. They have exactly same brutto-formula, but different structure and very different properties. The first is a gas, the second is a liquid easily reacting with sodium metal.

Carbon is also interesting example. It has two common forms with exactly same chemical formula $\ce{C}$, but very different properties: a very hard and transparent diamond and soft black graphite.

Answer (score 0):

Examples from geology abound, and are probably more interesting to everyday folks.

- Titanium dioxide, $\ce{TiO2}$ is commonly found in a [rutile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutile) form that has a body-centered cubic tetragonal strucutre, but [anatase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatase) has tetragonal pyramidal crystal structure.  Rutile has very unusual optical properties that anatase does not have; and conversely, anatase enjoys catalytic properties that rutile does not.  This system very well studied by chemists and materials scientists.
- Hydrated magnesium silicate, $\ce{Mg3Si2O5(OH)4}$ comes in a bewildering array of polymorphs.  Several (chrysotile, tremolite, anthophyllite, amosite, crocidolite, and actinolite) are collectively known as [asbestos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asbestos).  Their unusual fibrous crystal structure led to their use in a variety of fire-resistant applications until it was realized that inhaling fine shards of these minerals was a major health hazard.  In contrast, [lizardite](http://www.minerals.net/mineral/lizardite.aspx) is also a hydrated magnesium silicate with formula $\ce{Mg3Si2O5(OH)4}$, but does not have a fibrous crystal structure and is not hazardous.

Some examples from biochemistry are also very interesting because they matter to folks' everyday lives.

- Trans fats like [elaidic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaidic_acid), $\ce{C18H34O2}$ were previously abundant in the food supplies of many Western countries because of partial hydrogenation of plant-derived vegetable oils.  Dietary consumption of trans fats is now believed to be a major health hazard.  However, the *cis* isomer of elaidic acid is called [oleic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oleic_acid).  It is the major component of olive oil and other plant-derived oils, and is not believed to be hazardous.  It's formula is also $\ce{C18H34O2}$.